# iptables v1.4.10: can't initialize iptables table `NAT': Table does not exist

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, nat, kernel

```
xxx:~# iptables -t NAT -A PREROUTING -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/bad_list, it will be ignored in a future release.
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.
iptables v1.4.10: can't initialize iptables table `NAT': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

xxx:~# uname -a
Linux xxx.server4you.net 2.6.38-2-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 29 16:45:36 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The previous kernel was 2.6.32, iptables 1.4.2 and the problem was the same. Current kernel was built manually from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's case sensitive.

It should be

iptables -t **nat** -A PREROUTING -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2